# Не закрывается приложение Windows

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!

Имеется приложение Windows, состоящее из трех форм, открывающихся по очереди. Открываясь, они соответственно скрывают предыдущую форму. По непонятным обстоятельствам, теперь после открытия третьей формы приложение полностью не закрывается, т.е. не освобождает процесс. Для кнопки выхода использую `Application.Exit()` метод. Но выдается следующее исключение:

> Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления.

Что это означает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрывают каким образом? Close или Hide? Если Hide, то всё понятно: главная форма остаётся открытой, но невидимой и продолжает прослушивать сообщения Windows, и сколько не закрывай другие формы, приложение не остановится.

Чтобы остановить приложение, надо закрыть главную форму - ту, которая передавалась в Application.Run

Comment: Я использую Hide, но дело в том,что как раз таки я и закрываю главную форму методом Application.Exit() и в этот момент выдается исключение об ошибке.

Comment: Не надо вызвать Application.Exit

Вызывайте Close  у главной формы.

Answer (score 0):

> Коллекция была изменена; невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления.

Это означает, что мы итерируем коллекцию, а в это время кто-то модифицировал её (а может, мы сами внутри своего цикла сделали такое). В Java есть аналогичная ошибка: [ConcurrentModificationException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). Здесь суть такая же.

Раз случается такая ошибка, то тут два варианта: баг внутри .NET или баг в вашем коде, который запускается при завершении приложения (например, обработчики закрытия окон что-то пытаются натворить перед смертью).

Comment: Кажется я понял причину, просто я использовал в приложении BackgroundWorker и видимо он не освобождает процесс, только вот как от него избавиться?

Comment: Так уничтожьте его: вызовите Dispose или CancelAsync